# Using Pandas to Extract From a .csv File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am attempting to answer the following question given a csv file with columns corresponding to final exam score and gender (among others). I understand how to solve using a for loop, but not pandas.

"Find the mean Final exam score for all females in the class."

```
import pandas as pd 
grades = pd.read_csv('samplegrades.csv',index_col=0)
grades['Final','Gender'== 'F'].mean() #Incorrect Line
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on correct syntax using pandas. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
grades.loc[grades['Gender'] == 'F', 'Final'].mean()
```

Answer (score 3):

[**Option 1 is given by @Vaishali**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415199/2336654)
Most idiomatic answer.

---

**Option 2**

```
grades.query('Gender = "F"').Final.mean()
```

---

**Option 3**

```
grades.groupby('Gender').Final.mean().loc['F']
```

---

**Option 4**

```
grades[df.Gender.eq('F')].Final.mean()
```